# Creating bussiness role Many to many relationship

Tags: erd

Just a question to know if my logic are true or not? I'm kinda confuse here either to use 1-M relationship or M-M relationship

I have table `user` and `Event`

(User can join multiple event that they want)

Can I do this relationship as M-M ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a many-to-many relationship, because one user can participate in several events and an event consists of several users.

Comment: thank you! I you cleared up my head. Will mark your answer in 1 minute. Due to the timer :)